# How to move html with a tracking pixel to a different server?

Tags: tracking, pixel

There is a web page with tracking pixels (and probably other tracking code) that I would like to move to my own server.  Viewing the page on the current server generates a page view as expected, but when I move the html (exactly, without any changes) to my own server, the hits are not registered.  I'm trying to understand why - is it possible that the tracking mechanism can determine the IP address of the requesting page?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an external js file involved in the tracking, you'll need to add that too.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  One more question if you don't mind.  I see that the js code is "packed" in the html page.  I can unpack it with a website called jsunpack.jeek.org, which lets me download a zipped file.  Is this the right format to put into the directory in the new server?  Also, the zipped file has a long name like: cdc7/576a0a2eaf5e44564875cb17d443cd0046b8.zip.  Is this the name I should call the file?  The other alternative is readable_file_name.js, the name that appears in the html.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with js packing, but I would think the packed file should work fine on your server as it is.